# Loopback 4: Environment variables are undefined when I put it in a constant and import it

Tags: node.js, typescript, strongloop, loopback

I have a folder in which I have all the env.proccess variable.

src/config:

```
export const TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE = process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE
export const TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN_VALUE = process.env.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN_VALUE;
```

I have another class JWT.service

```
...

import {TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE, TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN_VALUE} from '../../config';

...

      console.log("MYENV: " + TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE); //RETURN UNDEFINE
      console.log("MYENV: " + process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE); //RETURN A VALUE
```

The other thing that is getting me crazy is that if I write in src/config:

```
export const TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE = process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE || "HELLO".
```

I get in my other class JWT.service

```
console.log("MYENV: " + TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE); //RETURN HELLO.
```

Why my constants are not taking the value of the process.env? why my constants return undefined when process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE has a value?